# Statsmodel sandwich "all groups are empty taking lags" error when using HAC-Panel clustered standard errors

Tags: python, statsmodels

I have data that looks like this:

| account | DV | month | year | yearmonth | pre/post | group |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 121 | oct | 2019 | oct 2019 | pre | control |
| 1 | 124 | Nov | 2019 | nov 2019 | post | control |
| 2 | 120 | oct | 2019 | oct 2019 | pre | treatment |
| 2 | 118 | nov | 2019 | nov 2019 | post | treatment |

I run a difference-in-difference regression:

```
results2 = smf.ols("DV ~ C(group, Treatment('control')) * C(pre_period, Treatment(True)) + month + C(year)",
                  df99).fit(cov_type='HAC-Panel', cov_kwds={'groups':df99['account'], 'time':df99['yearmonth'], 'maxlags':35})
print(results2.summary())
```

And I get the error message below.
I do the same thing with a different dataset that is more or less the same (different experiment) but do not encounter the problem. My data cleaning process is essentially identical. Furthermore, just a few days ago, this was working fine. But it has now suddenly thrown up this error (I did reverse any changes I had made).

I can't make sense of this error at all. Even searching for this error message in "sandwich_covariance.py" doesn't reveal anything.

This person has had a similar problem but no solution was proposed: [Python statsmodels robust cov_type='hac-panel' issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61465483/python-statsmodels-robust-cov-type-hac-panel-issue)

```
  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-43-0dcbaef1325b> in <module>
----> 1 results2 = smf.ols("dv ~ C(group, Treatment('control')) * C(pre_period, Treatment(True)) + month + C(year)",
      2                   df99).fit(cov_type='HAC-Panel', cov_kwds={'groups':df99['account'], 'time':df99['yearmonth'], 'maxlags':35})
      3 print(results2.summary())

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/pyr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/statsmodels/regression/linear_model.py in fit(self, method, cov_type, cov_kwds, use_t, **kwargs)
    340 
    341         if isinstance(self, OLS):
--> 342             lfit = OLSResults(
    343                 self, beta,
    344                 normalized_cov_params=self.normalized_cov_params,

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/pyr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/statsmodels/regression/linear_model.py in __init__(self, model, params, normalized_cov_params, scale, cov_type, cov_kwds, use_t, **kwargs)
   1584                     use_t = use_t_2
   1585                 # TODO: warn or not?
-> 1586             self.get_robustcov_results(cov_type=cov_type, use_self=True,
   1587                                        use_t=use_t, **cov_kwds)
   1588         for key in kwargs:

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/pyr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/statsmodels/regression/linear_model.py in get_robustcov_results(self, cov_type, use_t, **kwargs)
   2530             groupidx = lzip([0] + tt, tt + [nobs_])
   2531             self.n_groups = n_groups = len(groupidx)
-> 2532             res.cov_params_default = sw.cov_nw_panel(self, maxlags, groupidx,
   2533                                                      weights_func=weights_func,
   2534                                                      use_correction=use_correction)

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/pyr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/statsmodels/stats/sandwich_covariance.py in cov_nw_panel(results, nlags, groupidx, weights_func, use_correction)
    785     xu, hessian_inv = _get_sandwich_arrays(results)
    786 
--> 787     S_hac = S_nw_panel(xu, weights, groupidx)
    788     cov_hac = _HCCM2(hessian_inv, S_hac)
    789     if use_correction:

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/pyr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/statsmodels/stats/sandwich_covariance.py in S_nw_panel(xw, weights, groupidx)
    723     S = weights[0] * np.dot(xw.T, xw)  #weights just for completeness
    724     for lag in range(1, nlags+1):
--> 725         xw0, xwlag = lagged_groups(xw, lag, groupidx)
    726         s = np.dot(xw0.T, xwlag)
    727         S += weights[lag] * (s + s.T)

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/pyr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/statsmodels/stats/sandwich_covariance.py in lagged_groups(x, lag, groupidx)
    706 
    707     if out0 == []:
--> 708         raise ValueError('all groups are empty taking lags')
    709     #return out0, out_lagged
    710     return np.vstack(out0), np.vstack(out_lagged)

ValueError: all groups are empty taking lags
```

Comment: try with smaller `'maxlags'`. Maybe your maxlags is larger than the number of observations (yearmonths) in each group.

Comment: Thanks Josef. I have experimented with different `maxlags` amount but I'm still getting the same error. Any other ideas?

Comment: Hey Josef, I think I have isolated the problem to the `groups` specification. If I put in some other variable, e.g. `treatment group`, it runs without any errors. But this is of course not what I am clustering by, so ultimately does not work. Any ideas as to why putting `account` in group is causing this error?

Comment: Further to that, using `cov_type='cluster` with `account`, seems to work fine.

Comment: Do you have your data sorted by account, so that time periods for an account are in consecutive observations?  Also you could try `hac-groupsum' which has a different ordering of hac and cluster robust computation.  https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.regression.linear_model.RegressionResults.get_robustcov_results.html Otherwise you need to provide a minimum working example to see what's going on in this case.

Comment: Josef, I'm so sorry for having wasted your time on my stupid mistake. Somewhere along the way my data, which was sorted by account, got re-sorted by time instead. I should've noticed, but thank you so much for pointing it out. I will put in answer to solve this question. Thanks again, and in general thanks for all the answers you've provided across this site.

Answer (score 0):

As our statsmodel saviour Josef has very rightly pointed out. The problem was simply that data was not sorted in the way that I had shown in my example.

Data should be sorted by the group you are clustering on (in my case `account`), then by time. This is as per the documentation:

> ‘hac-panel’ heteroscedasticity and autocorrelation robust standard errors in panel data. The data needs to be sorted in this case, the time series for each panel unit or cluster need to be stacked. The membership to a timeseries of an individual or group can be either specified by group indicators or by increasing time periods.

If for whatever reason you are not able to sort the data in that way, as Josef points out, you can use `HAC-groupsum` instead which works even if the data is not sorted. The results are of course slightly different.